# What's the best way to open source data (rather than code)?

Tags: open-source, data-visualization

As part of a recent programming project I compiled a database, the contents of which may conceivably be of use to someone else one day. I'm looking for the best way to 'open source' the data.

I could (and probably will) upload the SQL onto GitHub, but was wondering if anyone had found a more 'data-centric' way of sharing - maybe a website that makes it easy for users to browse/query/visualise/improve data sets, rather than just giving them a big lump of SQL.

To clarify, I'm looking for a place where I can share the data, rather than a format in which to share it - ideally a data-set equivalent of GitHub/Sourceforge.

The data is relatively small (a few thousand lines of SQL) so the volume should not be an obstacle.

Comment: What is the subject of the data?

Comment: And how large is the data set? Can a user reasonably download it quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Amazon's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for stuff like this. And if your data set is interesting enough, maybe you could publish it with [InfoChimps](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/new).

Comment: Seconded - the infrastructure provided by InfoChimps makes this a much easier route than self-distributing.  If one does self-distribute, the S3 provides a good hosting option.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with a lot of data from different companies. Most often this data has been in text delimited data format. The most popular of course being comma separated or tab. Using comma's is often a good choice because MySQL can also export and import CSV. Here is an example:

```
id, first_name, last_name, address
1, John, Smith, 11222 Stree Name
```

Answer (score 1):

[Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables) ticks some of these boxes, although the emphasis seems to be on visualisation (I haven't used it, so this may be unfair). I am also reluctant to commit too heavily to any second-tier Google products these days, since they have a habit of disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

You could export it to XML, that being probably the most compatible data format, although it is rather verbose. Another solution is [OData](http://www.odata.org/), but this implies hosting the data and the platform that serves the data which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

[Sparkfun](https://data.sparkfun.com/) is another possibility, it seems to be mainly targeted at real-time data sources but they offer free storage and the platform is open-source so you can host your own server.